# How to let users enter multilingual text data for same column in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing a portal with Django. I need that my users can enter texts in multiple languages and I should be available to get it with the locale name:

E.g. `name['en'] , name['de']`

So for that case, what Django model should I use? Something like Dictionary?

Edit: I found something for translation:

http://code.google.com/p/django-transmeta/

Any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [django-modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/) in many projects, it works fine.

**Features**

- Unlimited number of target languages
- Add translations without changing existing models
- Django admin support
- Supports inherited models

**Update:**

You can also use some others

- [django-multilingual](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/)
- [django-multilingual-model](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual-model/)
- [i18ndynamic](http://code.google.com/p/i18ndynamic/)

But personally I have experience with [django-modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/).

Comment: Had not heard of django-modeltranslation before. Looks pretty good. I'll have to roll out translation in a project pretty soon, so I think I'll give this one a go. Thanks.